# Structure XML nodes using DOM in ABL

Tags: xml, dom, progress-4gl

I'm creating an XML file using ABL.  I want the detail node to fall below field3 like this:

```
+<root>
     +<header>
        <field1>some data</field1>
        <field2>some data</field2>
        <field3>some data</field3>
       +<detail>
           <field4>some data</field4>
        </detail>
      </header>
  </root>
```

However, this is what's happening when the XML file is saved. The detail falls directly under the header node.

```
+<root>
     +<header>
       +<detail>
           <field4>some data</field4>
        </detail>
        <field1>some data</field1>
        <field2>some data</field2>
        <field3>some data</field3>
      </header>
  </root>
```

Is there a method I can use or specific way I need to order/structure my code to achieve this?

Here is the code for the node creation:

```
hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hRoot,"root","ELEMENT").
hDoc:APPEND-CHILD(hRoot).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hHeader,"header","ELEMENT").
hRoot:APPEND-CHILD(hHeader).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hDetail,"detail","ELEMENT").
hHeader:APPEND-CHILD(hDetail).
```

I'm adding the value's for the detail node after field 1-3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you showed a complete example.

Comment: If the relationship (between nodes) is correct and tags are correct the receiving side should be able to parse the xml correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question this seems to do what you are describing:

```
define variable hDoc    as handle no-undo.
define variable hRoot   as handle no-undo.
define variable hHeader as handle no-undo.
define variable hDetail as handle no-undo.
define variable hField  as handle no-undo.

create x-document hDoc.
create x-noderef  hRoot.
create x-noderef  hHeader.
create x-noderef  hDetail.
create x-noderef  hField.

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hRoot,"root","ELEMENT").
hDoc:APPEND-CHILD(hRoot).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hHeader,"header","ELEMENT").
hRoot:APPEND-CHILD(hHeader).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hField,"field1","ELEMENT").
hHeader:APPEND-CHILD(hField).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hField,"field2","ELEMENT").
hHeader:APPEND-CHILD(hField).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hField,"field3","ELEMENT").
hHeader:APPEND-CHILD(hField).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hDetail,"detail","ELEMENT").
hHeader:APPEND-CHILD(hDetail).

hDoc:CREATE-NODE(hField,"field4","ELEMENT").
hDetail:APPEND-CHILD(hField).

hDoc:save("file","test.xml").
```

From your undesired output example I would guess that you are appending the "detail" element to the header first.  If you want it after field3 you would need to append it after field3 has been appended. Or you could use the INSERT-BEFORE() method rather than APPEND() if you either "walk the widget tree" to the appropriate point or maintain an appropriate pointer.